# Change model resting pose

Tags: modeling

Currently trying to learn blender I have a model that I downloaded and I am editing it to learn a bit about blender, the initial model came with heels and I want to change this model to be flat footed whats the best way to go about this?[image]

Comment: Does it have animations?

Answer (score 2):

After changing the pose in Pose Mode, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and `Apply Pose as Rest Pose`

[image]